# Laravel 5.4. No query results for model при обращении к Route::post-экшену

Tags: php, laravel, route

Доброго времени суток. Делаю мягкое удаление для ресурса, при переходе в виде по ссылке "Восстановить" (ссылка посылает POST к route('announces.restore') ), выдаёт

```
NotFoundHttpException
No query results for model [App\Announce].
```

**routes/web.php:**

```
Route::resource('/announces', 'AnnounceController');
Route::post('/announces/{announce}/restore', 'AnnounceController@restore')->name('announces.restore');
Route::post('/announces/{announce}', 'AnnounceController@softDelete')->name('announces.softDelete');
```

**AnnounceController@restore:**

```
public function restore(Announce $announce) //если обойтись без объекта модели, работает
{
    $announce->restore();
    return redirect()->route('announces.index')->with(['message' => 'restore.success', 'id' => $announce->id]);
}
```

**views/announce/index.blade.php:**

```
<a href="{{ route('announces.restore', ['announce'=>session('id')]) }}"
   onclick="event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('restore-form').submit();">
   Восстановить
</a>
<form id="restore-form" action="{{ route('announces.restore', ['announce'=>session('id')]) }}" method="post" style="display: none;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Я реализовал немного по-другому экшн:

```
public function restore(Request $r)
{
    $id = $r->announce;
    $a = Announce::onlyTrashed()
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->restore();
    return redirect()->route('announces.index')->with(['message' => 'restore.success', 'id' => $id]);
}
```

Это работает, однако хотелось узнать, почему не получается через объект модели это сделать. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что по умолчанию эти записи не попадают в запрос, в этом то их и фишка.

[Цитата](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models) из официальной документации:

> As noted above, soft deleted models will automatically be excluded
>   from query results. However, you may force soft deleted models to
>   appear in a result set using the withTrashed method on the query